# Why Bheeshma being an Avatara of Ashtavasu and pious with his karma had to die in a tragic way?

Tags: mahabharata, karma

Bheeshma being an Avatara died in a tragic way. He had to sleep on an arrow bed till death. 
Why this happened? What karma succumbed him to death in  such a horrific way? 
Is there any reason provided by any author?

Comment: I heard that he had thrown a snake in the bush of thorn..due to this karma he had to sleep on an arrow bed...